# Unable to get value from html to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here I am sending data of mail id and its visibility to server for two different users for one I have included mail and its visibility and for another  hiding visibility.

To hide visibility I am using `<div ng-if="atom.type === 'person'">`.
Hiding and showing is working properly but problem is that on both case
it is showing visibility undefined.

If I am not using  `<div ng-if="atom.type === 'person'">`. then it is properly sending visibility.

How to resolve this?

My Code is bolow

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMessages']);
myApp.controller('profileInfo', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.authorized = false;
  $scope.visibility = ["Private", "Friends", "Public"];
  $scope.id = 0;
  $atom.type = 'person';
  $scope.addMailId = function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $scope.mailidDetaillD = {
      'mailidDetaillList[0].email': data.mailid,
      'mailidDetaillList[0].visibility': data.visibility,
      'pageId': $scope.id,
    };
    console.log($scope.mailidDetaillD);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.9/angular-messages.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<dd class="col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7">
  <div class="pull-right" ng-if="authorized">
    <a ng-click="showAddMailIdDiv()" ng-model="addMailIdLink">add MailId Details</a>
    <div class="add-school" ng-show="showAddMailId">
      <form action="AddMailId" id="AddMailId" name="addmail" cssClass="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-lg-2">
            <label>Mail Id</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <input type="text" ng-model="mail.mailid" name="mailid" placeholder="Enter mail id" required class="form-control" />
            <div ng-messages="addmail.mailid.$error" ng-if="addmail.mailid.$touched">
              <p class="field-err" ng-message="required">MailId Required</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-if="atom.type === 'person'">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-2">
              <label>Visibility</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <select ng-model="mail.visibility"
                      ng-init=" mail.visibility = visibility[1]"
                      ng-options="x for x in visibility"
                      class="form-control"
                      name="mailvisibility" required>
              </select>
              <div ng-messages="addmail.mailvisibility.$error" ng-if="addmail.mailvisibility.$touched">
                <p class="field-err" ng-message="required">Select Mail visibility</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-lg-2">
            <label class="sr-only">Submit</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6 pull-right">
            <input type="button" value="add" ng-click="addMailId(mail)" ng-disabled="addmail.$invalid" cssClass="btn btn-sm btn-primary" />
            <input type="button" ng-click="hideAddMailIdDiv()" value="cancle" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" />
          </div>
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</dd>
```

last console.log is showing following result

```
  mailidDetaillList[0].email: "W@w.com"
  mailidDetaillList[0].visibility: undefined
  pageId: 2337
```

after removing `<div ng-if="atom.type === 'person'">`

```
  mailidDetaillList[0].email: "ss@s.com"
  mailidDetaillList[0].visibility: "Public"
  pageId: 2337
```

Comment: I guess what you need is `ng-show` instead because `ng-if` removes element

Comment: Instead of setting visibility with `ng-init`, set it from the controller.  The `ng-init` directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of `ngInit`. See [AngularJS ng-init Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit).

Comment: Could you output the value of `atom.type`, first?

Comment: `atom.type` value is `person` or `page`

Comment: @georgeawg I was not included following line is question $scope.visibility = ["Private", "Friends", "Public"];

Comment: Did you define your default "mail" object? $scope.mail = { email: "default_value",  visibility: "default_value"}

Comment: Also don't use "data" parameter in "$scope.addMailId = function(data)". Just read values from the $scope.mail object

Comment: ok i will update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the `ng-init`:

```
  <select ng-model="mail.visibility"
          ̶n̶g̶-̶i̶n̶i̶t̶=̶"̶ ̶m̶a̶i̶l̶.̶v̶i̶s̶i̶b̶i̶l̶i̶t̶y̶ ̶=̶ ̶v̶i̶s̶i̶b̶i̶l̶i̶t̶y̶[̶1̶]̶"̶
          ng-options="x for x in visibility"
          class="form-control"
          name="mailvisibility" required>
  </select>
```

And set visibility from the controller:

```
  $scope.mail = { visibility: $scope.visibility[1] };
```

AngularJS is an [MVC - Model-View-Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) framework. The framework renders the View from the Model. The Controller creates the Model. Using `ng-init` to create the Model is going the wrong way. It makes an App that is difficult to understand, test, debug, and maintain.

The `ng-init` directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of `ngInit`. See [AngularJS ng-init Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit).